# Why is the button not showing any fade-in-out effect?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a button where, on hovering, will produce an ease-in-out effect. I used the following code:

```css
#quotebutton {
padding:20px;
margin-top:-55px;
/* fallback/image non-cover color */
background-color: #000;
/* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000), to(#333));
/* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000, #333); 
/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000, #333);
/* IE 10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000, #333);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000, #333);
font-size:18px;
color:#fff;
float:right;
transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#quotebutton:hover {
/* fallback image non-cover color */
   background-color: #000;
   /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#333), to(#000));
   /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #000); 
   /* Firefox 3.6+ */
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333, #000);
   /* IE 10+ */
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333, #000);
   /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333, #000);
}
#quotebutton a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

The HTML is as below:

```
<div id="quotebutton">
<a href="">Download Now</a>
</div>
```

But the button is not showing the effect on hovering. What might be the problem?

Comment: I don't think gradients support transitions. you can do this with background images, though. http://w3conversions.com/sandbox/css3/transition/trans-back.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer is that you can't animate background gradients with CSS3 transitions. There are a few ways that you can accomplish the same goal using alternative techniques:

1. Use jQuery to animate a transition between two different background images on hover. You can accomplish this most easily by stacking three elements on top of each other using absolute positioning, where the bottom two are the background images and the top contains the content, which in this case is your button text. On hover, fade out the top background image to reveal the bottom one smoothly. See [this tutorial for making a background animation on hover with jQuery](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/simple-call-to-action-button-with-css-jquery/).
2. Use a semitransparent gradient background in conjunction with a webkit transition to create a partial animation. CSS3 transitions can easily animate the background-color CSS attribute, which is only visible through nonexistent or transparent background images or gradients. See [this example for an idea of how you might implement this](http://jsfiddle.net/kb7P7/).

Of the two options, (1) is more flexible but more work and requires a companion script, while (2) is less flexible and less cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks for being so informative, I will try both ways and check out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Ryan mentioned, you cannot animate background gradients.
Although, there are jQuery plugins that help you accomplish that.

Try [jQuery Blend](http://www.jacklmoore.com/blend)

Another idea I have, is to apply a linear transparent gradient image on top of a solid color.
You can then animate the solid color with transition. The transparent gradient image on the top will make it look like a gradient animation.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Rahul. Can you please show me how I can use to apply the linear gradient on top of solid color?

Comment: Sure, check this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsv/Kf59W/
If it helps, please don't forget to mark as answer :)